# Vue.js - Element UI - Form item label slot

Tags: vuejs2

I would like to know how to use `Form Element Slot` with `vue.js 2.3` and `element-ui`. [Documentaton here](http://element.eleme.io/#/en-US/component/form). So I can insert  `html` for the label of my form.

I tried this on `jsfiddle` [here](https://jsfiddle.net/yk5zqu3d/).

#### Problem

> Unknown custom element: el-form-item-slot

#### Question

What is the proper way to implement that? The documentation is not clear on this topic

Comment: `el-form-item-slot` doesn't appear to be the tag name for any of the components included with the Element UI library

Comment: Definetely not, hence my question. The feature is supported since `1.3` but I don't know how to use it. I saw that but don't know how to apply it https://github.com/ElemeFE/element/pull/4634

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The way to specify content to use in a component's slot is by adding the `slot` attribute to an element within the tag for that component.

In your case, you want to specify an element to go in the the `label` slot for the `el-form-item` component. You could do something like this:

```
<el-form-item label="temp">
  <span slot="label">Label for the slot</span>
  <el-input v-model="formLabelAlign.name"></el-input>
</el-form-item>
```

Notice, I did have to also provide a `label` attribute (with value `"temp"`) to the component tag itself. This might be a bug or it might be a required (and poorly documented) fallback value.

[Here's a working fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/ua3ozu2z/)